# Flattening nan values causes errors

Tags: python, list, pandas, nan

I am trying to flatten a python3 list that has `nan` in it and it is causing an error.

The code I am using to flatten the list is

```
def flatten(x):
    if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
        return [a for i in x for a in flatten(i)]
    else:
        return [x]
```

from [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists). It works great for lists like
`[1,[123,132], 1]`
but it doesn't work on my list `[nan, ['fiction', 'flash', 'short-story'], nan, nan, nan]`
The nans come from empty spaces in the pandas DataFrame.

I get the error `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp`

Comment: If you're sure, your values will be lists, you could use `def flatten(x) return [a for i in x for a in flatten(i)] if isinstance(x, list) else [x]`?

Comment: The problem is not nans but the strings. `isinstance('str', collections.Iterable)`  returns True. John's suggestion would solve that.

Comment: @JohnGalt yes that worked. Thank you.